# For two triggers(before insert and after insert),is it allowed for you to use where in the NEW keyword

Tags: mysql

I have two triggers.One after insert trigger and the other before insert trigger.The two triggers are using the `NEW` keyword to get the last inserted message.

Both triggers are watching a table called `incoming_sms` and the row inserted has three fields. `Id,name,service`

Service contains a unique number `9999999` for first service and `8888888` for second service.

Is it possible that when using the `NEW` keyword that i also use where `service = 9999999` just to be sure i am referring to the right last inserted message by specific service.

If i just use `New.col` without specifying the service,i may be referring to the wrong service since i will get the last inserted value by any service.

I hope i explained that clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will notice that triggers in MySQL include `FOR EACH ROW`.  The values in `NEW` alias always, only, ever refer to the specific row that invoked the trigger. There is no ambiguity.

If multiple rows are inserted in a single query, the trigger fires individually for each row, so in each iteration through the trigger you can test any of the `NEW` columns.